# python, exponentiaiton with 'def' and 'for-loop'

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, increment, exponentiation

**input:**

```
numbers = [1,2,3]
increment = 5
```

**Expected output:**

```
[1, 32, 243]
```

**Result with my code:**

```
1
32
243
```

**Code:**

```
def power(x, y):

    if (y == 0): return 1
    elif (int(y % 2) == 0):
        return (power(x, int(y / 2)) *
            power(x, int(y / 2)))
    else:
        return (x * power(x, int(y / 2)) *
                power(x, int(y / 2)))

for number in numbers:
    exponentiation = power(number,increment)
    print(exponentiation)
```

I'm trying to find the square root of the numbers in a list without pow() and '**' functions. I've found the square root of each number, but I'm wondering how to put them in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the exponentiations, but instead you want to output the list.
This is what you want to do:

```
# your function code above

answer = []
for number in numbers:
    exponentiation = power(number,increment)
    answer.append(exponentiation)

print(answer)
```

This will give:

```
[1, 32, 243]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make an empty list before the for-loop, then inside the for-loop, instead of printing each number, append it to the list. Then at the end, print the list.

```
def power(x, y):

    if (y == 0): return 1
    elif (int(y % 2) == 0):
        return (power(x, int(y / 2)) *
            power(x, int(y / 2)))
    else:
        return (x * power(x, int(y / 2)) *
                power(x, int(y / 2)))

output_list = []

for number in numbers:
    exponentiation = power(number,increment)
    output_list.append(exponentiation)

print(output_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use single line for loops -

```
exponentiation = [power(number,increment) for number in numbers]
print(exponentiation)
#[1,32,243]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the pow function of the python library and append value in the list and print list instead of individual value

```
numbers = [1,2,3]
increment = 5
l=[]
for i in numbers:
    ex=pow(i,increment )
    l.append(ex)
print(l)
```

output

```
[1, 32, 243]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, if I were you, I would use this code.(Exponentiation = [number ** increment for number in numbers])